# Are birthdays celebrated in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

We've seen that age is a factor when it comes to Jedi Training.

My questions; **are birthdays *celebrated* in the Star Wars universe** and **is there a specific ceremony (such as a party) associated with them?**

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Life_Day!

Comment: @Richard First of all, that's not really a birthday. Secondly, no. Just no.

Comment: How are birthdays celebrated on Earth? Your answer will vary greatly depending on where you are in the world. Traditions from the US, to China, to Africa are all different. Now you are asking about a universe made up of hundreds of different species each with thier own unique regional traditions? Maybe narrow this down.

Comment: Does your Question mean how time is measured and tracked and how events are dated in Star Wars, considering that every planet has different day and year lengths, aside from different cultures using different calendars? This makes defining a meaningful and standarized "age" of a person difficult.

Comment: @Hothie, no, I mean are birthdays celebrated?  i.e. is there an annual celebration on the anniversary of one's birth?

Comment: There was actually a typo in my question.  The original asked, how are birthdays celebrated?  When I meant to ask, are they celebrated?  Question has been fixed.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero not only different cultures, but different lengths of time (day lengths, year lengths, etc. and also differing lifespan scales, and probably different counting-bases).  e.g. a yoda-species might celebrate every 36 yoda-homeworld years (assuming he uses a base 6 counting system for his 6 fingers) and to avoid too many birthdays throughout hundreds of years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [main canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media) of Star Wars (the 6 films, the Clone Wars TV series and film, the Rebels TV series) there are no special mentions of birthdays being celebrated although it's pretty clear that families do recognise them.

In the '[Empire Day](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907220451/http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-rebels-2014&episode=s01e07)' episode of Rebels, it's noted that Ezra's birthday is on the same day as the eponymous Empire Day. Suffice to say, it's a bit of a downer.

Also, as @DustinJackson has pointed out in his answer, the occasion of a Padawan reaching the age of 13 is supposedly celebrated with a [small ceremony](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padawan_birthday_ritual) and marked by a gift-giving. Although this isn't mentioned in the main canon shows, it does get a brief mention in the Star Wars Encyclopedia.

---

Moving down the canon scale, there are numerous mentions of birthday celebrations in the various EU novels and comics.

**[Legacy of the Force #5](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force:_Sacrifice)**

> “You think the war will be over by then?” “If it’s not, we’ll still
> have a party. All of us.”Uncle Han and Aunt Leia, too? Even after I
> tried to arrest Uncle Han?” And that was the bizarre reality of a
> civil war: a teenage boy sent to detain his aunt and uncle, and **then
> fretting over whether they’d attend his next birthday party.** Mara
> sometimes tried to add up the days she’d lived that weren’t about
> killing and warfare, and there were so very, very few. She wanted a
> different future for Ben.

**[Dark Forces : Soldier for the Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Forces:_Soldier_for_the_Empire)**

> Hong nodded and turned away. Kyle gave a sigh of relief, waved the men
> forward, and followed the handwritten signs. They read “Comm Center”
> and led him past what smelled like a cafeteria, a series of cavelike
> storage rooms, down a businesslike corridor. **The rough-hewn walls
> supported an electronic message board and a hodge-podge of printouts.
> One announced a birthday party for someone named Blim Shahar**, and
> another cautioned base personnel to conserve on water.

**[Jedi Apprentice: The Only Witness](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Apprentice:_The_Only_Witness)**

> Qui-Gon felt slightly relieved. At least there was an explanation for
> the easy entrance.
>
> Lena adjusted one of the holoscreens until it showed a large dining
> room filled with people.
>
> **“It’s Bard’s birthday,” Lena said with relief. A large Fregan birth
> celebration banner lay across the dining table. “I should have
> remembered.”**
>
> The crowd milled about the room, smiling and carrying glasses filled
> with red liquid. At first glance it looked like any other party.
> Qui-Gon looked harder.

**[Clone Wars : Gambit : Stealth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Wars_Gambit:_Stealth)**

> She recognized it immediately: The Spring Symphony by celebrated Naboo
> composer Tofli Argala. She’d mentioned once, in passing, that Argala
> was her favorite of all Naboo’s music makers. Trust Bail to remember.
> **He knew she’d been homesick of late, having to miss little Pooja’s
> birthday celebrations again.** Of course she’d sent a gift and commed on
> the day, but a holographic aunt wasn’t the same. Pooja deserved
> better.

**[X-Wing : Wedge's Gamble](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X-Wing:_Wedge%27s_Gamble)**

> “He had graduated from the Academy and was assigned to a Star
> Destroyer-the Accuser. **On the occasion of his birthday-something most
> TIE pilots celebrate because of their rarity**-he was engaged in a
> realtime HoloNet connection to our home. His family was there: father,
> mother, brother, sisters, grandparents, and his fiancee. He was
> speaking to them when the transmission was cut off.

**[Ewoks 2 : Rites of Power](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewoks_2:_Rites_of_Power)**

[image: Meanwhile at Princess Kneesaa's birthday celebration in the Ewok village... Kneesaa: "Oh Father! This is the most wonderful birthday I've ever had! And my gifts are beautiful!"]

Comment: If you want more, there's at least 30 other examples I could have used. I though this would make a good representation since it covers Jedi, Naboobians, Empire soldiers and Rebel soldiers

Answer (score -1):

In a word, no. I am speaking of my own personal experience and I have read a couple dozen canonized novels and watched every series and movie to this point (though I missed a couple episodes of "The Clone Wars").

In all of those pieces of work I have viewed the only "celebration" of a birthday I have seen so far is when a Padawan graduates to Jedi knight.....but I am not sure if that counts. I am sure some cultures have celebrations of Birthdays but I have never heard or read of them specifically.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there are dozens of references to birthday celebrations in the Star Wars novels.

Comment: Actual birthdays? I have seen celebrations in the books, but do not recall any specific references to them being about the age of an individual? It is possible that I missed one considering I don't study the books with a passion though.

Comment: There's loads. I'm just throwing together an answer now.

Comment: @Richard Great answer, but I am not totally sure if a comic book counts as canon though :)

Comment: There are now only three levels of canon; Canon, "Legends" and Non-canon. The books and comics are Legends canon; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon